# Is it possible to configure IP addresses through Grails?

Tags: tomcat, grails, ip

Apologies if this is a silly question. This question was brought up at work, due to switching to DHCP, over static addresses. Our main developer is gone, and did not pass on if this is possible beforehand. My understanding is it is done through Tomcat.

Comment: This touches so many different levels, that I don't have a clue about the background of your question: The IP of the server is typically completely separated from applications running on top of it (e.g. tomcat/grails). Unless your application connects to some IP address - Tomcat just binds to an IP address that is available - often to all of them, but that can be limited. In that case, it's rather a configuration question than one of application code (grails)

Answer (score 0):

If you have some links that are hard coded in the Views or Controllers, yes, you will have to change those IP addresses in Grails.  For example, if you have a picture or icon that is being pointed to a specific server address and folder, you will have to change it in Grails.

On the other hand, if you want to use a different port for you app, you will have to change it in Tomcat.